# What is different between static variable and variable in class extension?

Tags: objective-c, static-variables, class-extensions

Static variable "Declaring a variable static limits its scope to just the class—and to just the part of the class that’s implemented in the file" (Apple doc).

And I think a variable was defined in class extension has a limit scope in just only the class define it.

That is similar !

What is different between static variable and variable in class extension ?

Answer (score 7):

The `static` variable is tied to the file it's defined in. It's not accessible from outside of that file, and there is only one place for storage created for it in your entire program.

The distinction about storage also applies to non-static global variables -- there will only be one in your program.

A variable in a class extension is likewise limited in visibility to the file in which it's declared, but it's an *instance* variable. There's a new piece of storage attached to each instance of the class you create.

If you create a `static` variable and change its value from several instances of the class, every instance will see the same value. That is not the case with an ivar -- each object can change and retain its own value for that variable.

(This is why `static` variables are sometimes used in ObjC to simulate class variables, which are present in other languages.)